# Finding the centre point between 3 approximate measurements

Tags: trigonometry

Say you have 3 erroneous distance measurements $a, b, c$ to a point $T$, taken from three different locations, $A, B, C$, how would you go about finding the "best guess" for $T$, where the "best guess" is such that it reduces the deviation from each measurement, $a, b, c$, respectively.

For example:

*Alfred, Bruno and Chris measure a tree, they all use the same range finder which will give an answer incorrect by the same amount each measurement. Alfred is at (1, 1), Bruno at (6, 3) and Chris is at (2, 7) - [as visualised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8IDG.png)*

*Alfred reports a measurement of ~4km, Bruno ~3km and Chris measures ~5km - [as visualised with circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyqf4.png)*

*What is the true location of the tree?*

Setup in [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/yvtcuhms)

I think this should also be generalisable for any number of points

Comment: First of all, consider separately abscissas ans ordiantes. Then consider that the average is not always the best thing to do; You can in particular consider median. See for example https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/03/06/student-t-distribution-mean-median/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be measured using the technique called Trilateration.

[image: Trilateration visual]

Let the three colored circles represent the area reported by the independent range finders.

Combining the measurements, we can conclude that the target must be in the intersection of the three circles i.e, the yellow shaded area since the three range finders reported a ping from the same object.

So, you create a triangle with a point $T$ that is $a, b, c$ distance apart from the vertices. We know the location of the centers of each circle using the given coordinates which correspond to the vertices of the triangle. From that we determine $T$ using geometry of triangles.

Comment: thank you! trilateration is the term I needed to google!

Comment: Why would the centroid be the correct answer, this seems arbitrary ?

Comment: You are right. T doesnt have to be centroid. I'll edit the answer.